# Cron Expression - Subtraction or Date Offset

Tags: cron

I'm not very well versed in Cron expressions and struggling to find out whether something is feasible.  Is it possible to create an expression for every 2nd Wednesday of the month minus 52 days?

The 2nd Wednesday of the month our known starting point and then want to subtract off it to run that on an ongoing basis.  Maybe there is a smarter way to write this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly in the cron time specification.  I would do it by running a command every Sunday (52 days before a Wednesday is a Sunday) and then check if the date 52 days into the future is between 8 and 13, inclusive:

```
0 0 * * 7 DATE=$(date --date='now+52 days' +\%-d); [ $DATE -ge 8 -a $DATE -le 13 ] && some command
```

(Note that percent signs are special in crontabs and need to be escaped.)

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately but I like the solution and I think it solves the problem without me giving more details.  I was actually trying to make it work for Quartz scheduler which doesn't seem to like this expression.